Jupyter Notebook Cannot Open
First I have got the below error from jupyter notebook

/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
(base) elliewu@Ellies-MBP ~ %
/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit; Traceback
(most recent call last):   File
"/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/traittypes.py",
line 232, in _resolve_classes
klass = self._resolve_string(klass)   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py",
line 2015, in _resolve_string
return import_item(string)   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/utils/importstring.py",
line 33, in import_item
module = import(package, fromlist=[obj]) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in

sys.exit(main())   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
line 283, in launch_instance
super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
line 1073, in launch_instance
app = cls.instance(**kwargs)   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py",
line 583, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py",
line 1292, in new
inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py",
line 1335, in setup_instance
super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py",
line 1311, in setup_instance
init(self)   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/traittypes.py",
line 223, in instance_init
self._resolve_classes()   File "/Users/elliewu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/traittypes.py",
line 235, in _resolve_classes
warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning) TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only
argument: 'stacklevel'
Saving session... ...copying shared history... ...saving
history...truncating history files... ...completed.
[Process completed]

Now,I can't launch or open Jupyter Notebook. When I open this error comes first. Need help please.
Thanks.

See the first paragraph in my answer here.
